# How to check for at least TWO common members on two lists in python?

Tags: python, list

I have the code that checks for at least one common item:

```
def common_members(list1, list2):
    for items1 in list1:
        for items2 in list2:
            if items1 == items2:

    return False
```

How do I revise this code such that it checks for TWO common items in two lists?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sets.html) to check how many items from several lists intersect:

```
len(set(items1).intersection(items2)) >= 2
```